# How to convert yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: mysql, date, format

I would like to convert yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy format.So, I am using strtotime() function.but when I get zero date like(0000/00/00) from mysql. It will be showing wrong date like(01-01-1970).

I need exact string like 0000/00/00 to 00/00/0000. any other function are there?

Comment: fathak, welcome to SO. Please specify what language/framework.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for functions in MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

Try MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateColumn FROM table...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
strftime("%d-%b-%Y", strtotime($value['your_date']));
```